# React mapping is suddenly showing error, which was working fine for a month

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a MERN stack project. I am working on that for like a month. I used parcel to create react app, and worked unit until yesterday. As per request I changed it to create-react-app.

So for a while it worked fine in create-react-app. But when after I build the project all the map() functions are showing error.

This is the JSON file of my mongoDB Collection.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60db452a8fe38d2860d03426"
  },
  "description": "Sample desc.",
  "dateRange": "July 24, 2021 - July 25, 2021",
  "status": "Post",
  "date": "2021-06-29",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1624982826539"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1625234700197"
    }
  },
  "__v": {
    "$numberInt": "0"
  }
}
```

This is the coding of the page

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class AboutUsBody extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        dates: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:6060/aboutus/view')
        .then(response => {
            const dates = response.data;
            this.setState({ dates });
            console.log("response", response);
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(error.message);
            console.log("Error", error);
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.dates.map((item, index) =>
                <div>
                    {item.status && item.status === 'Post' &&
                        <div>
                            <div className="text-center container" style={{ fontSize: "110%", fontStyle: "italic" }}>
                                <p className="pt-2 ps-2 pe2">{item.description}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-center container" style={{ fontSize: "200%" }}>
                                <p>{item.dateRange}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            )}
        </div>

    );
}
}export default AboutUsBody;
```

This is the error I am getting
[image: Error]

As it worked for like a month I don't understand why it suddenly showing this error. Please help me to identify what the error is.

Console.log(dates)
[image]

console.log(response)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you call :

```
this.setState({ dates });
```

you are setting dates as an object or map only apply to array.

it should just be :

```
this.setState( dates )
```

or if the response is an object :

```
this.setState([dates])
```

Comment: If I change like ([dates]) or (dates) the error is gone, but the data is not rendering  (Unable to see the data)

Comment: is the response data not too long so you can paste it in the comment ?

Comment: Its too long. I have added the screen shot of it  in the question

Comment: Yes. This was in the dates

Comment: does the screenshot come from console.log("response", response) ?

Comment: Yes from this console    ` .then(response => {
            const dates = response.data;
            this.setState({ dates });
            console.log("response", response);`

Comment: can you console.log(response.data) instead because this what you have in dates not response.

Comment: I am sorry . Actually I checked as `console.log(dates)`. The above screen shot is for response.data. I have added the screen shot of both

Comment: Seems like your backend send the wrong data, cant really help you...

Answer (score 0):

You're logging the `response`, so verify that `response.data` is actually an array. If it's not an array, that's why (because you're trying to use the `map` method on something that isn't an array).

From some quick testing, only Firefox uses the error text "TypeError: (foo).map is not a function", and only when the object is defined but isn't an array. So, I"m guessing your server is now returning an object instead of an array.

Comment: Can you tell me what I need to do to make it work. I have added the databade(JSON) too.

Comment: That request is returning HTML, not a JSON object like you're expecting. And, the HTML looks like a React index page. I think you're passing the wrong URL to `axios.get()`

Comment: Oh I think when I try to deploy it in heroku, may be at that time the link is collapsed